# What does hierarchy support do in cgroup?

Tags: linux, memory, cgroups

`cgroup` has 2 options for memory control:

- `memory.use_hierarchy = 1` : use hierarchy
- `memory.use_hierarchy = 0` : use flat hierarchy, according to [this answer](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1209.0/00867.html)

What is the difference between the two? I think, hierarchy is hierarchy, what does "flat" mean here?

I read the cgroup documentation [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt#580) explained the hierarchical support:

> In the diagram above, with hierarchical accounting enabled, all memory
>   usage of e, is accounted to its ancestors up until the root (i.e,
>   c and root), that has memory.use_hierarchy enabled. If one of the
>   ancestors goes over its limit, the reclaim algorithm reclaims from
>   the tasks in the ancestor and the children of the ancestor.

- What does it mean by `accounted to its ancestors up until the root`?
- How can ancestors can go over its limit, since its children capacities are allocated that sum to the capacity of the ancestor?
- Why are tasks reclaimed in both ancestor and children? I thought that tasks are only allocated in the children and those tasks automatically belong to ancestor. i.e. "WWW Browsing" has 20% capacity; its children are "Professors" and "Students" that have 15% and 5% respectively. The maximum can never exceed 20%. Why is there a case in the document stated that:

> If one of the ancestors goes over its limit, the reclaim algorithm
>   reclaims from the tasks in the ancestor and the children of the
>   ancestor.

Comment: As I said on SuperUser before you deleted the question there (next time, flag for moderator attention if you want a question migrated to another site in the StackExchange network), "the tasks in the children of the ancestor" is a fully contained subset of "the tasks in the ancestor". So by reclaiming from the tasks in the children you also automatically reclaim from tasks in the ancestor. I don't *know* whether or not it in fact is so, but it is a plausible reading of the text as written (although I agree it could be phrased much better).

Comment: @Michael Kjörling thanks I will ask the moderator to move my question next time. Also, what you said make sense.